# DurableEntity - Mocking SignalEntityAsync

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using SignalEntityAsync to trigger an operation on durable entity.
`await starter.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, "Reset");`

How could I mock this call? I am using Nunit and tried mocking in different ways. But it does not work. Getting an error:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mock it in following manner:

```
_durableClient.Setup(x => x.SignalEntityAsync(It.IsAny<EntityId>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), "Reset", null, null, null)).Returns(It.IsAny<Task>());
```

In my azure function have following code:

```
EntityId entityId = new EntityId(nameof(MessageCounter), nameof(MessageCounter));
await starter.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, "Reset");
```